# Hotkey for Trash (Recycle) for Windows

Tags: windows, hotkeys, recycle-bin

Keyboard shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is opening Explorer (My Computer) on Windows.

Is there a way to run Trash (Recycle) with a shortcut like <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, excepting utilities?

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because it's to much of a workaround but you could create a shortcut to the recycle bin and add a keyboard shortcut to that through Right-Click -> Properties -> Shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no shortcut to open the Recycle Bin. 
Here is a list of all shortcuts: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/126449

What you can do (and what I always do as soon as there is no shortcut functionallity I want but Windows doesn't offer it) use AutoHotKey.

After installation you simply can create a script (that may hold all your shortcuts). Compile and start the created executable. Add to Autorun if you want it to start on boot.

Here's a list of Folders for Windows from the [AutoHotKey Froum](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/8661-how-to-open-the-recycle-bin/). A script example is also in the thread.